# A common term for Promote and Demote?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I have been working on a software where there is a section to promote and/or demote other users. 
For last two days, I have been thinking and searching for a common term to group both of these terms together but it seems like I am out of luck or I am searching in the wrong direction.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a proper term or word which can convey the meaning of promotion/demotion or level change on itself without requiring any further explanation to the user?